# How to execute adb shell commands that includes granting permissions to subfolders in /data/data directory from a Python script with os.system?

Tags: python, adb, chmod, os.system, su

I'm trying to execute the following series of adb commands in one line using os.system:

```
OnePlus5:/ $ su

OnePlus5:/ # cd data/data && chmod -R 777 ./

chmod: chmod 'lib' to 120777: Read-only file system
chmod: chmod 'lib' to 120777: Read-only file system
chmod: chmod 'lib' to 120777: No such file or directory
chmod: chmod 'lib' to 120777: Read-only file system
chmod: chmod 'lib' to 120777: Read-only file system
chmod: chmod 'lib' to 120777: Read-only file system
chmod: chmod 'lib' to 120777: Read-only file system
chmod: chmod 'lib' to 120777: Read-only file system


1|OnePlus5:/data/data # exit


1|OnePlus5:/ $ exit
```

Here's the line from my Python script that supposed to do it:
`os.system("adb shell su -c 'cd /data/data && chmod -R 777 ./; exit' && exit")`

here are the two lines from the console that are related to this line:

```
su: exec failed for cd Error:No such file or directory
adb: error: failed to copy '/data/data/xxxxxx' to './xxxxx': remote open failed: Permission denied
```

I then need to pull a spcific file in a folder that is in the data/data folder with the new permissions given earlier using `adb pull` but I can not do it as you can see above.

**My device is rooted**

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: My device is rooted. When I execute the series of commands one by one as I showed above, I can use adb pull on this directory

Comment: Instead of messing all the directory permissions I would try to install an adb version that allows the `adb root` command and thus can directly pull from `/data/data`. Or alternatively just copy the file to be pulled to /sdcard or try to pipe out the fIle using `adb exec-out` in combination with su and cat.

Comment: How can I install the adb version you're talking about? Is there a recommended one? I've tried to use `adb root` in the current version I have installed - it didn't help

Comment: Sorry but quite some time passed since I last used an "insecure" adb version. You need an adb version that does not drop root permissions after startup. On some versions this can be configured using the config `ro.adb.secure` if this mode is enabled adb drops root permissions after startup.

Comment: I am looking for an alteration I can make in my code rather than using a different adb version. I'll wait for more suggestions. Thanks!